# Best way to handle spaces in formatting while cloning in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, clone

So I have some jQuery working here: http://jsfiddle.net/8VtZf/

[image]

This is how it looks at the start... There are (1) and (2), and when I click the add button, it will clone the last one, and increment the number. This is all working fine and the information starts as:

```
<div class="inputClones">
    <input class="inputButton" type="button" name="result[]" value="1" />
    <input class="inputButton" type="button" name="result[]" value="2" />
</div>
```

The problem comes when I click the clone button. Cloning will happen to the element, but it wont preserve formatting... with the result code as follows:

```
<div class="inputClones">
    <input class="inputButton" type="button" name="result[]" value="1" />
    <input class="inputButton" type="button" name="result[]" value="2" /><input class="inputButton" type="button" name="result[]" value="3" /><input class="inputButton" type="button" name="result[]" value="4" />
</div>
```

[image]

Because of that, the inherint spacing between (1) and (2), will be lost between added clones. What would be the best way to add this extra spacing?

Comment: You should use CSS for that. Different browsers have different inbuilt stylesheets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A trick you could use is to set the font-size of the parent element to 0. This works because the odd spacing is caused by the lack space characters between subsequent the `input` elements.

```
.inputClones {
    font-size: 0;
}
```

[Here's a working fiddle for the above](http://jsfiddle.net/8VtZf/1/).

If you want to customize the *spacing* between the buttons, just add a margin-right to the inputButtons.

```
.inputButton {
    margin-right: 8px;
}
```

[Working fiddle with custom button spacing](http://jsfiddle.net/8VtZf/4/).

If you want the actual space characters to remain, well I think you're out of luck.

Comment: But what if I WANT the space?

Comment: @JasonAxelrod then check my answer. Only way to guarantee consistency.

Answer (score 0):

Add constant margin in css like

css:

```
.inputButton  {  
margin-right:1%
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="inputClones">
    <input class="inputButton" type="button" name="result[]" value="1" /><input class="inputButton" type="button" name="result[]" value="2" />
</div>
<br />
<input type="button" value="Add Button" class="addButton">
```

jquery without any modifications
[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8VtZf/5/)

Comment: CSS is not the solution... since it still has the extra space in the first element... Basically the margin to the right becomes margin-right: 1%... PLUS the extra space. Its not constant.

Comment: with html which I provided there is **no** problem ;) added demo especially for you

Answer (score 0):

Relying on the browser to style and layout elements is a bad idea. You'd be much better off defining some CSS for the buttons:

```
.inputClones input[type="button"] {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
    .inputClones input[type="button"]:last-child {
        margin-right: 0;
    }
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8VtZf/2/)